# Implement search for two draggable flatlist in react-native

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I'm working on an app to create a search for two draggable flatlist on the same page, not sure how I should start, the search should work across both the lists and also it should not break the existing state.
I'm maintaining the position of the draggable flatlist so the search should hold the positioning as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to find the solution, as I was using single arraylist with two different objects for the two lists so I made it workable by manipulating it on the parent container